# Jmeter request keeps giving 403 where postman works & browser works

Tags: jmeter

I use post man and I am able to run a request perfectly fine with status 200

```
https://abc/api/
```

when I try Jmeter I keep getting 403 forbidden

```
GET https://abc/api/
```

I get

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Sampler request

```
Thread Name: 0-test1-1
Sample Start: 2019-07-22 11:07:12 PDT
Load time: 485
Connect Time: 378
Latency: 485
Size in bytes: 287
Sent bytes:236
Headers size in bytes: 153
Body size in bytes: 134
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 403
Response message: Forbidden


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html
DataEncoding: null
```

My response headers are

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: aws../2.0
Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2019 18:13:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 134
Connection: keep-alive
```

Note sure if that is

I also set my port to 443 because it is https

I was able to get content-type to application/json but still get 403, I do notice that my content-length is 0

Comment: no that link does not tell me about Content type

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it was indeed the User-agent, I forced my Jmeter  in header manager
User Agent --> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36  it worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need add into the header of the request
 `Content-Type: application/json`